# Atom to RSS feed

Tags: java, rss, atom-feed

I have an RSS reader portlet in websphere portal, which adds the RSS feed and renders the feed items on it. I need to add Atom feeds also in the existing code. We use a third party API to parse the feed URL, add it and render the news items on the portlet. Need to add some logic in my Java code to initially recognize the Atom feed and convert it into RSS feed.

I tried the same using an converter (easily available online), but don't know how to integrate the logic in code.

Comment: Would an explanation like this help? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961182/is-there-is-any-way-to-find-the-given-urls-is-an-rss-feeds-using-java/3961270#3961270)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understood your question properly but if you need to do conversions between various feed formats, my recommendation would be to use [Rome](https://rome.dev.java.net/).

Comment: I am already using informa and want to integrate the conversion part (rss to atom) in the existing code,what about using feedburner?